# What are the conditions for zero to belong to a convex hull of a set of points

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry

What are the conditions on a set of data points such that zero belongs to the convex hull defined by these points. (A part from expressing zero as a positive combination of the data points with coefficients equal to one).

I am looking for some established results for the case of dimension 3 involving distances sign of the coordinates...

Thank in advance.

Comment: A point $P$ is within the convex hull of a set $S$ of points if and only if all planes through $P$ leave a point from $S$ on both sides of that plane; does this help?

Comment: Yes, this seems promising. Could you please add more results of this type (if you still have any). 
Could you please show me a link to the theorem?

Comment: I'ven't a link; but you can easily see that for a point outside the convex hull, there must be a plane through the point that does not cross the convex hull (as a result of convexity), and then the result follows.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. Is there any similar condition for zero to lie on an edge or a face?

Comment: It lies on a face if there is exactly one plane through $P$ such that all the points are either on the plane or an a specific side, and lies on an edge if there are many such planes, but no such planes that fo not have a point *on* the plane.

Comment: Could be please explain the last part of your answer?

Comment: To lie on an edge, or a face, there can be no plane that passes through $P$ such that all the points of the hull are on one side of a plane. However, there must be planes through $P$ such that all the points are either on the plane or on one side (the same side); if there is one such plane, it is on the interior of a face, and if there are several, it is on an edge.

Comment: This may not be of use to you, but determining whether or not the origin is inside a convex hull can be determined by linear programming.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke could you please make clarify your answer?

Comment: I'm just pointing out that if you want an algorithm, as opposed to a mathematical characterization, it can be achieved by existing software for linear programming. And in arbitrary dimensions.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke, In fact I need this for a proof. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An algorithm to determine if 0 belongs to the interior of the convex hull defined by $n$ points $v_1,\ldots, v_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Without loss of generality, assume no two of the vectors are linearly dependent and not all of the points lie on the same plane.

For distinct $i<j$, define:
$$A_{ij}=\{v_k \cdot (v_i \times v_j): k\neq i,j \}.$$

Claim 1. If for all $i<j$, the set $A_{ij}$ contains both positive and negative numbers, then 0 belongs to the interior of the convex hull of $v_1,\ldots v_n$. The converse also holds.

Proof. First suppose 0 belongs to the interior of the convex hull so that $0=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i v_i$ and all $\lambda_i >0$ with $\sum_i \lambda_i=1$. For a fixed $i<j$, take the dot product of the two sides of the equation with $v_i \times v_j$ to get $0=\sum_{k\neq i,j} \lambda_k v_k \cdot (v_i \times v_j)$. Since $\lambda_k>0$ for all $k$ and the numbers $\lambda_k v_k \cdot (v_i \times v_j)$ add up to zero, at least one must be positive and at least one must be negative. Note that if they are all zero, then all of $v_k$s must lie on the plane spanned by $v_i$ and $v_j$ in which case the convex hull has empty interior.

Conversely, suppose 0 is not in the convex hull of $v_1,\ldots, v_n$. Let $P$ be a plane passing through the origin so that the entire convex hull lies on one side of the plane. Rotate the plane around any axis until it touches one of the points say $v_1$. All other points still lie on one side of the plane. Now rotate the plane around the line passing through the origin and $v_1$ until it touches another point say $v_2$. We have found a plane through the origin and $v_1$, $v_2$ such that one side of the plane contains no points from $v_1,\ldots, v_n$. Clearly all of the $v_i$s either make an acute or right angle with $v_1\times v_2$ or an obtuse or right angle with $v_1 \times v_2$. Therefore $A_{ij}$ cannot contain both positive and negative numbers.

Claim 2. If for all $i<j$, the set $A_{ij}$ is not a set of all positive or all negative numbers, then 0 belongs to the closed convex hull of the points.

Proof is similar to the proof of Claim 1. If 0 is not in the interior but in the closed convex hull, then clearly it is on the boundary.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. This is really helpful. Could you please put a link for the statement of the theorem?. I have also another question please, is there an equivalent version for zero to lie on an edge or on a face of the convex hull?